# How to determine the type of log device in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, terminal

I am creating the gem which is supposed to be run both inside and outside Rails. I don’t want to reinvent a wheel, hence I would either use the default logger or provide an ability for the user of the gem to create her own.

I have colored logs.

Creating the log device myself, I can easily check whether it’s a tty or not:

```
@logger = Logger.new(name)
@colorize = (IO === name) && name.tty?
```

Now terminal will receive colorized output, everything else will not. This works just fine.

Imagine though that I got an instance of `logger` from Rails:

```
@logger = Kernel.const_defined?(Rails) ? Rails.logger : Logger.new(name)
```

The only way to determine whether it is a `tty` looks ummm... too ugly:

```
Rails.logger
     .instance_variable_get(:@logger)
     .instance_variable_get(:@log)
     .instance_variable_get(:@logdev)
     .instance_variable_get(:@dev)
     .tty?
```

Am I missing something? Is there more elegant way to understand if Rails logger is spitting the output to terminal or not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rely on user's choice by using `config.colorize_logging` to decide(when running with Rails)?

Comment: There is no “user” in automatic tests environment and like. Furthermore, sometimes I have three different loggers attached to one process, with the only one to be colorized. Of course, I could show colors if and only explicitly requested, but it’s too annoying. Anyway. the question was about how to retrieve this information automatically..

Comment: By "user" i mean one that will use your gem. And maybe using global rails settings is not such fun such as colorizing everything :) but thus you will avoid running into situation where only your part of rails log gets colorized despite it was disabled explicitly in settings. By the way, it defaults to true.